# error filling array with class instances in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, object

Using Swift I am trying to create an array that is full of objects.  I keep getting this error instance member joe(first value) cannot be used on type 'Friend'(the class)

then i want to print the value of name for every object.  Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class Friend {

    var name:String = "aName"
    var athletic = 0
    var brains = 0
    var male:Bool = false

    init (name:String, brains:Int, athletic:Int, male:Bool){
        self.name=name
        self.athletic=athletic
        self.brains=brains
        self.male=male
    }

    let joe = Friend(name: "Joe", brains: 2, athletic: 3, male: true)
    let dave = Friend(name: "Dave", brains: 4, athletic: 4, male: true)
    let brent = Friend(name: "Bent", brains: 5, athletic: 1, male: true)
    let logan = Friend(name: "Logan", brains: 1, athletic: 5, male: true)

    var allFriends: [Friend] = [joe, dave, brent, logan]  //this is where the error occurs.

    for i in allFriends {
        print allFriends[i].name
    }
}
```

Please help thank you :)

Comment: Please fix your code formating.

Comment: If your let-statements are actually *inside* the class, then that's your problem and Mr Beardsley's answer is your fix

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace:

```
class Friend {

    var name:String = "aName"
    var athletic = 0
    var brains = 0
    var male:Bool = false

    init (name: String, brains: Int, athletic: Int, male: Bool){
        self.name=name
        self.athletic=athletic
        self.brains=brains
        self.male=male
    } // THIS IS THE MISSING BRACE
}

let joe = Friend(name: "Joe", brains: 2, athletic: 3, male: true)
let dave = Friend(name: "Dave", brains: 4, athletic: 4, male: true)
let brent = Friend(name: "Bent", brains: 5, athletic: 1, male: true)
let logan = Friend(name: "Logan", brains: 1, athletic: 5, male: true)

var allFriends = [joe, dave, brent, logan]  //this is where the error occurs.

for i in allFriends {
    print(i.name)
}
```

Comment: The brace is the problem. Copy and paste my above code into a playground or swiftstub. Works fine. Now delete the brace I mentioned. Notice you get the error mentioned by the OP.